# How can I render an image in a React Native application from a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, android, json, reactjs, react-native

Above I have JSON content in which an image's path is mentioned. I want to render an image in my React Native application. How can I render this image?

```
{"aImages":[{"obra_path":"http:\/\/upload.finarte.com.br\/images\/640\/3bcd2c863bdf329bf79e1e8aa1f2b41e.jpg"}]}
```

Comment: Hey, You could use the react native elements > Avatar component and directly supply URL from the json object to it. Googling this can help you out further

Comment: Thanks, Somangshu, but in my json file image URL inside array json then how to get url of this image from JSON response.

Comment: If it is always only one object in the array then you could either point directly to the 0th object (res.aImages[0]) or use underscore.js _.first(res.aImages) method

Comment: Can you ***not*** leave out punctuation, please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it like this:

```
<Image source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/logo-og.png'}}
       style={{width: 400, height: 400}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the JSON content, and you parse it with [Json.parse()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp). Then you set it in your state and use this state as your image source. See [oma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53040998/how-can-i-render-an-image-in-a-react-native-application-from-a-json-file/53041106#53041106) for that.